# See what a Cookie Container contains?

Tags: c#

How to check what all cookies were received....while debugging in VS2010?

```
                CookieContainer cookiejar = new CookieContainer();
                webRequest.Method = "POST";
                webRequest.Host = "www.site.com";
                webRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
                webRequest.UserAgent = "~~~~";
                webRequest.Accept ="~~~~";
                webRequest.Referer = "http://www.site.com";
                webRequest.CookieContainer = cookiejar;  
                HttpWebResponse webresponse =  (HttpWebResponse)webRequest.GetResponse();
```

`cookiejar <=` was showing a count of 6 cookie ..But i couldn't find any cookie values inside it.

Comment: Use [`GetCookies`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.cookiecontainer.getcookies.aspx) method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this-

```
if(Request.Cookies["key"]!=null)
{
   var value=Request.Cookies["key"].Value;
}
```

Please check upper/lower case if not working